# How to use openslide library in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, openslide

How should I install openslide library and load it in MATLAB? Using `openslide_load_library()` I got the following error: `libopenslide.0.dylib not available on the MATLAB path`

Comment: The error tells you that you haven't got the openslide library on your MATLAB search path. use `addpath(path-to-library)` to add it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the [OpenSlide MATLAB bindings by Daniel Forsberg](https://github.com/fordanic/openslide-matlab).

The installation instructions read (emphasis mine):

> Add the folder and any sub folders to the MATLAB path. Also download source code or binaries for OpenSlide from http://openslide.org/download/. If downloading the source, make sure to follow instructions provided by OpenSlide for compiling the binaries. **Remember to also add the folders of these libraries and the include files to the MATLAB path.**

It seems to me that you didn’t add the folders of the OpenSlide libraries and include files to the MATLAB path.